# Using a helper function to change a field of a query in Laravel 4 using DB:raw

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a query function that I am using to pull some data from my database.  I also have a function that changes around the "created_at" field to print it like so: Month Day YY'

Here is the query function:

```
public static function friend_activity_json($start = 0, $number_of_posts = 2) {
        $friend_activity = DB::table('fanartists')
                        ->join('fans', 'fanartists.fan_id', '=', 'fans.id')
                        ->join('artists', 'fanartists.artist_id', '=', 'artists.id')
                        ->orderBy('fanartists.created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->select(DB::raw('StringEdit::getDate(fanartists.created_at) as created_at, fans.fbid, fans.first_name, fans.last_name, fans.gender, fans.city, fanartists.artist_id, artists.stage_name'))
                        ->get();
```

The function is in the folder helpers, in a filed called "StringEdit.php".  The function is getDate:

```
public static function getDate($date) {
    $full_date = explode(" ", $date);

    $date_pieces = explode("-", $full_date[0]);

    $year = substr($date_pieces[0], -2);

    $monthNum = $date_pieces[1];
    $monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10));

    $final_date = $monthName ." ". $date_pieces[2] ." '".$year;

    return $final_date;

}
```

I have been able to call this function elsewhere, so I know it works.  How do I get it to work in this context to change around my "created_at" field?  When running this I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '::getDate(fanartists.created_at) as created_at, fans.fbid, fans.first_name, fans' at line 1 (SQL: select StringEdit::getDate(fanartists.created_at) as created_at, fans.fbid, fans.first_name, fans.last_name, fans.gender, fans.city, fanartists.artist_id, artists.stage_name from `fanartists` inner join `fans` on `fanartists`.`fan_id` = `fans`.`id` inner join `artists` on `fanartists`.`artist_id` = `artists`.`id` order by `fanartists`.`created_at` DESC) (Bindings: array ( ))
```

EDIT: New Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"%M %d %y) as created_at, fans.fbid, fans.first_name, fans.last_name, fans.gende' at line 1 (SQL: select DATE_FORMAT(fanartists.created_at, "%M %d %y) as created_at, fans.fbid, fans.first_name, fans.last_name, fans.gender, fans.city, fanartists.artist_id, artists.stage_name from `fanartists` inner join `fans` on `fanartists`.`fan_id` = `fans`.`id` inner join `artists` on `fanartists`.`artist_id` = `artists`.`id` order by `fanartists`.`created_at` DESC) (Bindings: array ( ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work like the way you used it in your query here

```
DB::raw('StringEdit::getDate(fanartists.created_at) as created_at, fans.fbid, fans.first_name, fans.last_name, fans.gender, fans.city, fanartists.artist_id, artists.stage_name')
```

Here, `getDate` function is being treated as `mysql` function and it's not valid, anyways, you can use `mysql`'s native `DATE_FORMAT` function instead, like

```
DATE_FORMAT(fanartists.created_at, "%M %d %y") as created_at
```

[Check the documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: using this I got another syntax error (added to my question in an edit)

Comment: @user1072337, there was a typo, I missed closing `"` after `%y`.

Comment: Can I use prepared statements with your DB::raw function ?